# body.Read undefined (type *io.ReadCloser has no field or method Read)

Tags: go

I can't seem to solve this weird error. Here's my code:

```
resp, err := http.Get("example.com/my/text/file.conf")
...
err = parseEvent(eventchan, &resp.Body)

func parseEvent(eventchan chan Event, body *io.ReadCloser) error {
raw := make([]byte, 1024*1024*32, 1024*1024*32)
n, err := body.Read(raw)
```

And i get this strange error:

> ./igen.go:91: body.Read undefined (type *io.ReadCloser has no field or method Read)

Row 91 is the `n, err := body.Read(raw)` line above.

What did I miss? Golang.org tells me ReadCloser implements Reader, which has the `Read(p []byte) (n int, err error)` method that I'm trying to call.

Comment: Take a look at the error message closely: `*io.ReadCloser`, not `io.ReadCloser`.  The function parseEvent should not be using a pointer to an interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

your parameter is `body *io.ReadCloser` - meaning a *pointer* to an interface. `ReadCloser`, the interface, has `Read()`. Just change your function signature to:

```
func parseEvent(eventchan chan Event, body io.ReadCloser) error
```

Comment: doesn't this mean pass by value, rather than by reference?

Comment: wait, do I pass the interface by value, but not the instance of the struct implementing that interface?

Comment: @FilipHaglund (sorry for the delay). If a struct implements an interface, a pointer to that struct still implements that interface. so you can pass the pointer as a value of the interface. it's a bit confusing at first, but once you get it, it's one of the most awesome principals of go.